# How can I tell which pins I will have left available by looking at a shield?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, pins, shields

I'm very new to Arduino and came to a point where I'm interested in playing with shields, such as LCDs.

For example, I really like the looks of "LCD 1602 with keypad" module, but it seems to be using a lot of pins.

- By looking at a module / shield, how can I tell (or at least estimate) which pins will be used and which ones I will have left if I stack them with my Uno or Mega without printed schematics?

Comment: look at datasheet

Comment: My question is asking about figuring out (or estimating) by looking at a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the 'Tutorials' section of [this page](http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-1602-lcd-keypad-shield-for-arduino-duemilanove-uno-mega2560-mega1280.html) you can see the pins used. All of the buttons come through in one analogue input and you'll need a further 7 digital I/O pins. So 8 in total which would leave 5 analogue and 4 digital (I think) pins on an Uno.

As for how to tell which ones, does it matter in advance? I would just map the I/O in the sketch to suit. If you need to plan that far in advance though, it seems that J5 in this [schematic](http://sainsmart.com/zen/documents/20-011-901/schematic.pdf) shows which pins travel through the shield (i.e. are available to use in conjunction with the shield). Also J6 shows the 5 remaining analogue pins.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use an i2c adapter for this type of display?
search for i2c display module.
i2c only needs 2 wires for data and clock and 2 for power.
you can also easily locate the SDA and SCL pins on your arduino